# How can I add Bridge.net to my existing c# project?

Tags: c#, bridge.net

I'm currently trying to add Bridge.net to upgrade from saltarelle. The project uses .net framework 2.0 so I downloaded Bridge version 1.12.0. I'm currently having an issue with the compiler detecting the updated Bridge attributes.

I downloaded Bridge from the nuget package manager. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, but it's still not recognizing Bridge.net attributes.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Items to add
    /// </summary>
    [Field]
    [DataMember]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1819", Justification = "The object is a POCO, the fact that the array is writable is irrelevant.")]
    public UpdateData[] Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

The field attribute is not being a detected.

I'm currently getting the following error: 
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Field' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What led you to the assumption of using Bridge 1.12.0 to support .NET 2.0? Bridge projects were not supposed to be targetted against .NET 2 at any point in its history. By targetting .NET 2 you probably are making it so Bridge's implementation would never work at all.

Comment: That's a good point. When I was doing the nuget package installation I would get errors saying the Bridge package required the project to target .NET framework >= 4.0, until I downloaded version 1.12.0. I made a probably incorrect assumption that there were no framework compatibility issues then. I haven't been able to find documentation on what the framework requirements are for each version of Bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't see a clear indication on what exact change triggered this .NET framework limitation in Bridge since version 1.13.0, Bridge was never meant to work under projects targetted against .NET Framework v2 (and not v1 also).

Yet, between [versions 1.12.1 and 1.13.0](https://github.com/bridgedotnet/Bridge/compare/v1.12.1...v1.13.0) the NuGet packages were rearranged in the hierarchy they look nowadays (introducing the Bridge.Core, Bridge.Min, and other packages, that are pulled from the main Bridge one). And this probably triggered a means for NuGet to identify this issue while installing in a .NET v2 project instead of just getting undone references.

That said, Bridge was always projected to reproduce .NET Framework 4 (down to 4.8.0), and thrives to reproduce the whole implementation where's possible. But there isn't a v2-focused version of Bridge, so .NET Framework project formats aren't supported by Bridge.

Not to lose all hope, this does not necessarily mean it shouldn't work. If you do some at your own. By chance, yesterday we had somebody in the community share a [.NET 2 project that claimed to output a simple "Hello World" with Bridge 17.9.0](https://github.com/samuelGrahame/DotNetFramework2). It was done by creating a .NET 4 project then switching to .NET 2 (public message in gitter). I see the project has `Bridge.dll` file copied and committed in the repo, so that may be also required to have Bridge working in that scenario.

In case the message ever becomes unavailable in gitter, here's a transcript:

> @Jpard6991 i was looking at it, i just changed the .net framework in the bridge library to 2 using nodepad++ then removed the reference to the bridge.dll and re-added that dll. changed to target .Net Framework 2.0 i got it to and show hello world.
>
> https://github.com/samuelGrahame/DotNetFramework2

Notice the Bridge's implementation of mscorlib is probably not going to match .NET Framework's, if any methods or classes parameters are different between the two versions, the Bridge project will be getting .NET 4 syntax instead of 2 in this case.

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful! I'm going to use Bridge to migrate from script sharp. It turns out that script sharp is the only thing holding the project to .NET 2.0 so once that's gone it should be on 4.0+ and won't have these issues.